# Can I switch all the stuff from my electric dryer to a gas dryer eliminating the gas burner

Tags: dryer

We purchase a Kenmore stackable washer/ gas dryer.  Can the gas dryer be converted to electric? We found out we don't have a gas line in laundry area.

Comment: I think that would depend on the definition of *can*. Generally speaking, any entity with enough money and time can accomplish almost anything! So, yes you can, given that you posses the know-how, technology, and will. Unfortunately, the practical answer is no. What *may* be an option is supplying a gas feed to the location; and it may not be as pain-staking as it sounds - but it's all situational.

Comment: If you have gas **to the house** just have a gas line run **to the laundry area** - it will pay back fairly fast, given the usual relationship between gas and electric prices.

Answer (score 5):

It may be *possible* to convert a gas dryer to electric, but it's not practical. Instead, I'd say you have two options.

## Install a gas line

If you have a gas supply into the home, you could have a line extended to the area near the dryer. It will cost a bit of money, but it's cheaper than trying to convert the dryer to electric.

## Return the dryer

Unless you bought the dryer on craigslist, a very long time ago, or from a not so reputable dealer. Most dealers will allow you to return the dryer, and exchange it for the correct item.  I'm sure dealers see this type of thing all the time, and that there are policies in place to deal with it.

Comment: If you did get it on Craigslist or Freeycle -- or even if you didn't -- putting it back into circulation via those services and getting an electric is an option. But I agree with @ecnerwal that you might want to take advantage of the mistake as a excuse to get your laundry area plumbed for gas. When I move my own laundry upstairs I'm seriously considering having it set up for both options, just in case I ever sell the house and some prospective buyer has an unreasonable fondness for electric.