# Can a gas dryer be converted into an electric dryer?

Tags: dryer

I am moving to an all electric apartment and have a gas dryer. It is 3 years old. Can it be converted to an electric dryer? How would I find someone to do this?

Comment: It's *possible* -- anything is *possible*; with the right amount of research, design, engineering, and hacking, you can make a car out of your gas dryer. The question is instead of *feasability*.

Comment: Until reading this question I had never heard of a gas dryer. Are they an American thing?

Comment: @TomWright - As a US citizen, I can safely say I've never seen a modern one.  There may be some in the north and midwest, but most of my life I've only ever seen electric ones in stores.

Comment: @Taegost - I'm surprised you've never seen one - they are pretty common in the midwest at least.  I don't think I've ever owned an electric dryer in fact.

Comment: @EricPetroelje - I figured it may be more common out there.  In New England (where I grew up), gas was used for heating and cooking.  I'm sure it may be used for other things, but I don't remember seeing it (Doesn't mean I haven't, I have a memory like a steel sieve!) down here in Florida...  I think gas may be used in places, but I've never actually seen any to say for certain if it's even used.

Comment: @Taegost They may only put electric dryers on display in stores, but virtually every dryer for sale can be bought in both electric and gas versions. Gas prices are generally cheaper than electric rates, making gas a much more attractive option for anything that will use it. Some areas just haven't been hooked up for gas, though, so it may be less prevalent there.

Comment: The price of natural gas has been dropping/dropped, making gas dryers cheaper to run than they used to be and often cheaper than electric. So anyone who hasn't bought a dryer recently might not have seen gas dryers for sale (as prominently) last time they did go dryer shopping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a gas dryer convert into electric?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/59358/can-a-gas-dryer-convert-into-electric)

Comment: Consider selling it and buy a compatible drier instead?

Comment: I suggest that while that might be possible, conversion will prolly cost at least as much as replacement…

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: I see your point, I should have stated that the last two paragraphs are something any DYI-er could do for himself with simple tools as a tune up for any residential dryer. It's like riding a bike, once you know what to do and what not to do, it gets easier. One of the main reasons for my previous post was that almost everyone commenting on the subject here and elsewhere made it sound too difficult or too expensive, and that it would make better sense to get rid of the gas dryer and simply buy an electric dryer.
Skill being in the eye of the DIY beholder, I am simply laying out the game plan fo

Answer (score 39):

In general, no you can't do this.

I suppose it's possible that the manufacturer uses many of the same parts between their gas and electric models and you could buy enough parts to do a conversion, but this would likely cost more than just buying an electric dryer in the first place.

But I've never seen a supported conversion kit - my advice: sell the gas dryer  and buy an electric.

Answer (score 4):

You might convert it to use propane. that way you can keep using it. There are some videos around how to do it.

Don't know about how it will affect its working, or longevity.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MC2xuQqQW0

[image]

Comment: I suspect that doing so safely (and with approval) of the apartment building would be much more expensive than just buying an electric dryer. Locating the propane tank safely outside of the apartment and running a gas line to the dryer's location will not be cheap. And then she'd still have to deal with refilling the tank periodically. A small tank may not even be large enough to handle the flow from  a dryer.

Comment: this is assuming cost is relevant. What if the gas dryer has significant emotional value and OP cannot be without it?

Comment: Oh the memories. If worse comes to worst and the propane conversion doesn't work out, the OP can still take it to a taxidermist to have it stuffed and put it on display in the living room.

Comment: Propane is a lot more dangerous than methane, since it is heavier than air. This is horrible advice.

Comment: With any sort of combustible is dangerous when handled improperly or with outdated worn equipment. By your logic one should convert it to hydrogen since its lighter than air

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could, but it doesn't make sense. Gas is almost always cheaper than electricity per kilowatt. So the operational cost is less for the gas dryer. In addition gas produces more BTU than electric so the gas dryer is more efficient and will dry the clothes faster. The only down side is the initial cost of the appliance is a bit higher for a gas dryer

Comment: If it's all electric, the OP doesn't have the choice of using gas. So cheaper to buy electric dryer over converting gas dryer to electric if that could even be done,

Comment: In most places (in the USA) you pay a monthly service fee to use gas before a single cubic foot of gas enters your home. (Mine was ~$42). If you want to be all-electric within 15 years you have to start somewhere. Why go all electric? Electric is cheap now and projected to get even cheaper. Gas pipes will have to be maintained over fewer customers over time (increasing service fees). The gas cost per cubic foot is also variable (see Russia-Ukraine). There's newer research that indicates gas appliances are akin to having a smoker in the house. And natural gas is awful for the climate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a mechanical control gas dryer can be converted to an electric dryer, just as a mechanical control electric dryer can be converted to gas. The newer computer controlled appliances may be problematic for conversions, i.e., too expensive to make it a feasible option, (but who knows, maybe flip a dip switch on the board and it might work just fine). Otherwise, on a mechanical control dryer, most of the parts are the same whether gas or electric(or propane which is a relatively simple, safe and inexpensive conversion from NG).

While I am familiar with Alliance products, I am fairly certain most dryers would be the same. As far as dryers go, manufacturers save time and money by having most options built into the cabinets and controls, in other words, most of the cabinet and moving parts of dryers are the same whether gas or electric, and have been unchanged for decades. What has changed, and not always for the better, are the controls and their consoles/panels. Mechanical controls seldom if ever breakdown in a residential setting, whereas computer controls can go bad for a variety of reasons and are expensive to replace.

The first thing would be to remove the parts specific to the gas dryer:the gas lead-in pipe assembly, shut off valve and elbow, igniter and bracket assembly, burner assembly, the coils and gas valve assembly and mounting bracket, heat duct shroud, combustion duct and limit thermostat, and the 110 power lead in cord.
Then we would replace all of the above with an electric heater kit (either 208 or 240 volts) which includes all wire assemblies, thermal fuse assembly, and limit thermostat, the mounting holes are already in the heater duct it attaches to.
Next comes the 220 terminal block and terminal block shield which attach to the backside of the rear bulkhead assembly, the mounting holes are already there on all dryers as are the 220 terminal block access cutout and cover on the rear of the cabinet, through which is installed the 3 prong or 4 prong 220 lead in cord.

And finally the wiring, the security cabinet harness assembly and wire harness assembly specific to the machine (front or rear controls) must be changed to the versions appropriate to the machine's serial number and the new electric heater.

For any looking at a gas to electric conversion, it would be wise to inspect/replace items such as the (2) cylinder rollers, and the (2) cylinder roller shafts, the cylinder belt, the idler lever and wheel assembly, and the flexible exhaust venting outside of the machine which may become clogged with lint.
Since most of the working parts must be removed from inside the dryer for this conversion, it is quite accessible to use of a vacuum to remove all lint inside the cabinet or the vents at the rear, and all that holds the motor and exhaust fan assembly is 2 screws and a power clip, so it doesn't take long to remove it and blow out any lint which has accumulated inside the blower housing and on the motor.

The kick panel on most dryers has 2 5/16 screws holding it on, and if you have someone who can remove it you can check to see if there is a buildup of lint inside, if so you should call for service, or if so inclined, unplug the machine and carefully vacuum out whatever lint is accessible because a buildup of lint inside the dryer is a fire hazard whether gas or electric.

Comment: Wow. Great answer! I find it amusing that after explaining all the how and expecting the OP to do that (this is a DIY site, after all), you suggest calling for service to clean out the lint. :D Of course, the question still stands, is it economically feasible to buy all the parts and change it out, or would it be cheaper to just buy a whole new dryer & sell this one as is. Looking forward to more of your well written, informative answers.

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts. Thanks, and welcome to the site!